# Creating a Sharepoint 2013 Masterpage

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have created a Masterpage through the Sharepoint 2013 design manager. I have been able to insert a few snippets such as searchbox, top navigation, logo.

When I then preview my masterpage. It looks fine except the content placeholder is underneath my footer - after  code. I want this to go into the body section but I can't find the placeholder snippet anywhere!

It shows this message below my markup:

"This div, which you should delete, represents the content area that your Page Layouts and pages will fill. Design your Master Page around this content placeholder."

but there is no content placeholder div in my masterpage.

Can anyone tell me how I get the content placeholder into the body section?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can add  to you master page. Or you can refer to the seattle.master page which already exists in the SharePoint 2013.

Comment: True but HOW was the question